# How to facet geom_bar with the original order of factor levels

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have problem to keep the original order in ggplot's `geom_bar` plot while faceting. Found some online help but they did not work when I tried to facet.

Code:

```
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x =rep(c("N-on", "N-off", "R-on", "R-off"),2),
            y = c(13,6,7,11,20,16,17,19), z = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4))))
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ z, ncol =1) +
  coord_flip()
```

Output:
[image]

Expected output: Labels in the vertical axis will be in original order e.g., `"N-on", "N-off", "R-on", "R-off".`

[image]

Comment: Use `data.frame(x=..., y=..., z=...)` to create your sample data. `cbind` creates a matrix and in this case coerces everything to character (because all elements of a matrix must be of the same type), which then gets coerced to factor by `as.data.frame`. That's why the y-axis of your plot is messed up.

Comment: According to your comment, I used:

>`df <- data.frame(x =rep(c("N-on", "N-off", "R-on", "R-off"),2),
                          y = c(13,6,7,11,20,16,17,19), 
                 z = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4)))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ z, ncol =1) +
  coord_flip()`

But output is same as before.

Comment: The y-axis is still in the wrong order?

Comment: @eipi10. Yes, vertical axis is same.

Comment: Vertical axis or y-axis? The y-axis is your numeric axis and is printed horizontally in your question (due to `coord_flip()`). Fixing the sample data frame will just fix the y-axis. Use @jMathew's answer (or my comment to his answer) to fix the order of the x-axis categories.

Comment: @eipi10: This code runs perfectly without `coord_flip()`. However, it messed up with  `coord_flip()`  `>df <- as.data.frame(cbind(p = rep(c("N-on", "N-off", "R-on", "R-off"),2), q = c(13,6,7,11,20,16,17,19), z = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4)))) 

df$p = (factor(df$p, levels=c("N-on", "N-off", "R-on", "R-off")))

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=p, y=q)) + geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~ z, ncol =1)`

Answer (score 6):

Apparently `geom_bar` plots in order of the levels of factor [ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5210833/2282381)

It seems that the order is preserved, in your plot except that its from bottom up. This seems to work,

```
df$x <- factor(df$x, levels=rev(levels(df$x)))


ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
geom_bar(stat="identity") +
facet_wrap(~ z, ncol =1) +
coord_flip()
```

Comment: Sorry it gives `"N-off", "N-on", "R-off", "R-on"` order instead of `"N-on", "N-off", "R-on", "R-off"` order. I do not sort but want to keep the order as it is. Thanks!

Comment: Then just do `df$x = factor(df$x, levels=c("N-on", "N-off", "R-on", "R-off"))` to get the order you want. In general, set the factor levels to whatever order you desire, and that's the order they will be plotted in.

Comment: I did this before but I am not sure why it is not working! Is is working when you run?

`df <- as.data.frame(cbind(x =rep(c("N-on", "N-off", "R-on", "R-off"),2),
            y = c(13,6,7,11,20,16,17,19), z = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4))))
df$x = factor(df$x, levels=c("N-on", "N-off", "R-on", "R-off")) 
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  facet_wrap(~ z, ncol =1) +
  coord_flip()`

Comment: Yes, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Finally reverse order of `levels` and using `data.frame` worked for me. Thanks a lot @eipi10 and @jMathew for your suggestions. I modified the code little bit to remove ambiguity.

```
    df <- data.frame(p =rep(c("N-on", "N-off", "R-on", "R-off"),2),
                          q = c(13,6,7,11,20,16,17,19), 
                          z = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4)))
#reverse order of the vertical axis data
df$p = factor(df$p, levels=rev(c("N-on", "N-off", "R-on", "R-off")))
#run ggplot
ggplot(df,        
       aes(x=p, y=q, fill=p)) +
  # adding or removing the aesthetic "order=vartype" doesn't change anything
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  facet_wrap(~ z, ncol = 1) +
  #facet_grid(. ~ z) + 
  coord_flip()
```

## Output:

[image]